# How to get list of columns from a query?

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

A PowerBuilder datawindow has some parameters and those parameters are obviously matched with columns in query of the datawindow. The query is too complex. In my script i get the query syntax in a string variable. Also i get parameters list defined in the datawindow. Now i want to get the list of columns from the query syntax where columns are being compared with retrieval arguments. I do not need those columns where column is not compared with retrieval argument.

for example query string has in its text **"product_price >= :prod_price AND SupplierID is null AND store_id = :storeID"**

I want to get all the columns names excluding supplierID because supplierID is not compared with any retrieval argument. The Query is too complex with many case statements and operators.

Is there any easy way to get columns list from the query string without involving complex string parsing script?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to get the list of columns defined in the resultset. That, however, can be different from the list of columns referenced in the query. And there is no functionality AFAIK that will associate a particular column with any parameter. So it seems the short answer is No - you have no choice but to parse the query. And do not forget that the "query" could be a stored procedure or function. You should try posting to the appeon forums.

Comment: Agree with @SMor, you’ve defined a very complex problem. Not only does your parsing have to be advanced (e.g. parse “words” at spaces, tabs, line breaks, certain but not all punctuation), but it has to be able to interpret those words in a SQL context (how would you know to ignore “is null”), and possibly in different SQL dialects. For instance, parsing this would give me nightmares: WHERE “STORE”.”COUNTRY_ID” in (“US”, “GB”, :country1, :country2). It’s definitely possible, but it’s not simple.

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify your problem is don't use parameters.

Instead of

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table where id = :id
```

try

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table where 1 = 2
```

In your code you can find and replace `1 = 2` with `id = 8675309`

Example

```
long ll_id = 8675309
long ll_start_pos
string ls_needle
string ls_replace
string ls_sql

ls_sql = dw_products.Getsqlselect()
//ls_sql = select col1, col2, col3 from table where 1 = 2

ls_needle = "1 = 2"
ls_replace = "id = " + string( ll_id )

ll_start_pos = Pos(ls_sql, ls_needle)

// Only enter the loop if you find ls_needle.
DO WHILE ll_start_pos > 0
    // Replace ls_needle with ls_replace.
    ls_sql = Replace(ls_sql, ll_start_pos,Len(ls_needle), ls_replace)

    // Find the next occurrence of ls_needle.
    ll_start_pos= Pos(ls_sql, ls_needle, ll_start_pos + Len(ls_replace))
LOOP

//Replace SQL
if dw_products.Setsqlselect(ls_sql) <> 1 then
    Messagebox("Error setting SQL select",sqlca.sqlerrtext)
return 1
```

Comment: That will increase code size like grass grows. i will have to change code for every datawindow. Splitting query in two parts does not solve the real problem. I understand what you mean by not providing parameters in datawindow design mode. if i have the where clause in a string variable in my script then how do i know which column is using which parameter (the variable in my script)? and if you are thinking that i can see with my eyes where which column should be matched with what variable then its real crazy idea. Lets say If you are managing code for already developed app then what?

Comment: Unless you are generating datawindow object at runtime the query splitting idea that way is not workable solution because any change in where clause will depend upon change in code.

Comment: How many datawindows? How far in the development process? What problem are you trying to solve? My example was as generic as the statement of your problem. If you'd like a more concrete solution then provide a more precise statement of the problem. We are here to help you.

Comment: One application that I work on uses precisely this strategy. The user is permitted to choose column filters. It is trivial to make a generic function that gets a list of all the columns in a datawindow and present them to the user (like querymode) and build a where clause to replace 1 = 2. One function used in the ancestor script of a window inherited by 40+ windows. Nice and tight with no "increase code size like grass grows."

Comment: "build a where clause to replace 1 = 2" and that is not what i am doing and neither it was asked in my question (generate dwo at runtime). The app has more than 4000 dwos. Actually Design mode of datawindow is not very perfect to use every bit of SQL Transaction 99% of the DWs was converted to syntax and then the queries were written in them. There is no way to revert back to design mode because design mode gives error on perfectly alright queries. If i pick every where clause then i will have to store it somewhere other than the dwo itself. really, throw me into deep dark well if i do that.

Comment: as i said before generating dwo can be based on many generic ideas. and i agree that some how any perfect framework can be developed. In current situation your idea will require query in two parts saved separately and without a  doubt that is horrible idea for me. The simple solution i am looking for is that i get query of any dwo in a string and then parse it to find columns.

Comment: but look like that is another horrible idea to get columns from a string. :)